# I've a not working AJAX function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a time management system for the place I work for. While coding it I've created a system which the user can configure the database details (like the wordpress first run install) and once the data is saved successfully I want to show the next step.

The first part is working perfectly but I've run into some issues with the second part where the system checks the connection and start creating the database and the needed tables.

Up to now I've been using JSON to send and receive `PHP` response text. But now I wanted to create a `AJAX` function to the same as `JSON`. But the problem is the `AJAX` function is sending the data but I can't get the response text.

I went through most of the SO titles came up when I did a google search (might have missed once) but none of them worked. When I try to get the output from an `alert` it shows as *oject[Object]* on the popup.

Below is my jquery which I have the `AJAX` coded into.

```
function checkResponse(){
    var res = $('#response').text();
    if(res === "Saved"){
        $.ajax({
           url: './bin/config/createConfig.php',
            type:'get',
            data:{check:'check'},
            dataType:'json',
            complete: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            }
        });

        // $('#nextstep').show();
        // $('#dbConfig-details').hide();
    }
}
```

Above function is called by the below `setTimeOut`.

```
if(noEmpty && confirm('Are you sure all details to be true?')){
            createConfig();
            setTimeout('checkResponse();', 1000);
}
```

This is the PHP which the above `AJAX` send data to.

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST["check"])){
    if(file_exists('../iConnect/node.php')){
        $readFile = file_get_contents('../iConnect/node.php');
        $dataTxt = unserialize($readFile);
        extract($dataTxt);

        try{
            $dbConnect = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbHost.';dbname='.$dbName,$dbUser,$dbPass);
            $dbConnect -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connected";

        }catch(PDOException $ex){
            echo "ERROR: ".$ex->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
    }else{
        echo "File missing";
    }
}
```

The `creatCofig()` code.

```
function createConfig(){
    var dbUser = document.getElementById("dbUser").value,
        dbPass = document.getElementById("dbPass").value,
        dbName = document.getElementById("dbName").value,
        dbHost = document.getElementById("dbHost").value;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST","./bin/config/createConfig.php?dbUser="+dbUser+"&dbPass="+dbPass+"&dbName="+dbName+"&dbHost="+dbHost,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I know I'm missing something with the `AJAX` but my knowledge is limited on `AJAX` can some one please show me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: It's showing `object[Object] ` because your returning an object! This is perfectly expected behaviour. Because your telling jquery that your returning json, it's parsing that json into an object for you.

Comment: `if(noEmpty && confirm('Are you sure all details to be true?')){
            createConfig();
            setTimeout(function(){checkResponse();}, 1000);
}`

Comment: I've read the comment 3 times now and I have no idea what your trying to say. It's an object, inspect it and see what it contains

Comment: @Liam sorry about my English, and I think I'm on to something after Roamers answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `complete` callback has a signature of `(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus)`.

Read about it here [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Try the following pattern :

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    type: ...,
    data: ...,
    dataType: ...,
}).then(function (data) {
    alert(data.responseText);
});
```

Also, don't rely on a timeout to wait for an ajax response. That's what promises are for.

In `createConfig()`, use `jQuery.ajax()` and return a promise as follows :

```
function createConfig() {
    return $.ajax({
        'type': 'post',
        'url': './bin/config/createConfig.php',
        'data': {
            'dbUser': $("#dbUser").val(),
            'dbPass': $("#dbPass").val(),
            'dbName': $("#dbName").val(),
            'dbHost': $("#dbHost").val()
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        $("#response").html(response);
        return response;
    });
}
```

Now you can write :

```
if (noEmpty && confirm('Are you sure all details to be true?')) {
    createConfig().then(checkResponse);
}
```

Comment: Thank you after reading for the 5th time I managed to get the function working.